# How do I create a .csv file with specific sqlite table fields using ruby and sequel gem?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, csv, sequel

The bottom code is supposed to create a new test table, add data from two existing tables and add the contents to a new csv file. The parsing of both existing tables works fine, and the .csv also gets created without error. The issue I'm having is that the .csv is being created with blank data except for the 3 "Fixnum" header columns above. I've tried multiple different things including numerous variations of string interpolation.

```
require 'sequel'

# Run time argv
DB = Sequel.connect("sqlite://#{db_file}")

# Load to_csv method via extension
DB.extension(:sequel_3_dataset_methods)

# Create test case
DB.create_table(:"#{table}"){
Fixnum :"News-1"
Fixnum :"News-2"
Fixnum :"Item-1"
}

# Parse news table
DB['SELECT one, two FROM news WHERE Id=12;'].each do |news|
#p news
end

# Parse item table
DB['SELECT news_feed FROM item;'].each do |item|
#p item
end

# Insert data into csv_file
1.times{|i|
DB[:"#{table}"].insert("#{news}", "#{news}", "#{item}")
}

# Open .csv file, write and save
File.open("#{csv_file}", 'w'){|f|
f << DB[:"#{table}"].to_csv                        
}
```

Comment: Your code example can't be executed.  You require sequel, but there's no code to create the `DB` constant. The code depends on other tables that aren't created, such as news and item. You don't need to use both `File.new` and `File.open`. Also, `Dataset#to_csv` isn't defined in recent versions of Sequel unless you use an extension.

Comment: All that code is included just not shown. On my question above I mentioned my code worked with the exception of the blank csv file. I will update the code to be complete. Those two item and news tables are already present in my sqlite file I'm just parsing them.

Comment: `news = DB['SELECT one, two FROM news WHERE Id=12;']`

Comment: Thanks steenslag. That was one of the diff things I tried but still produced an empty csv file.